# Basic Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

Just studying Threads in Android (I'm also a little new to Threads period). I'm looking at various other posts but still need a little clarification. I'm keeping it simple with HelloWorld. What I want to is display the Message: "Hello World this is a thread" with each word displayed at 1 second intervals. Thought use a string array with the message. Then use a for loop in the thread to iterate through each element. I'm pretty sure I understand the logic of my problem - in that the whole loop executes in the delay time frame. Can anyone tell me how I can break this out so I can display each element at 1 second intervals? Here is my code:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {

Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;
private TextView hello;

private String[] HelloWorld = {

        "Hello",
        "World",
        "This",
        "Is",
        "A",
        "Thread",

};
int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);
    hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

     m_handler = new Handler();
     m_handlerTask = new Runnable()

     {
         @Override 
         public void run() {
             if(i<HelloWorld.length-1)
             {
                     hello.append(HelloWorld[i]);
                     hello.setText("\n"); 
                     i++;
             }

             m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);
         }
    };
    m_handlerTask.run(); 
    m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hello_world, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using threads

```
     Thread thread;
     private String[] HelloWorld = {
        "Hello",
        "World",
        "This",
        "Is",
        "A",
        "Thread",

         };
     int i=0;
```

In your onCreate()

```
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

       @Override
       public void run(){
           for( i = 0; i < HelloWorld.length; i++){

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

              @Override
              public void run(){
                hello.append(HelloWorld[i]);
                hell0.append(" ");

              }
           });
           try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
         }

         }


     });
     thread.start();
```

I would suggest you to use a Handler

```
    Handler m_handler;
    Runnable m_handlerTask ;
    private String[] HelloWorld = {

        "Hello",
        "World",
        "This",
        "Is",
        "A",
        "Thread",

};
int i=0;
```

In your onCreate()

```
 m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
         @Override 
         public void run() {
             if(i<HelloWorld.length)
             {

            hello.append(HelloWorld[i]);
            hello.append(" ");
            i++;
             }
             else
             {
                 m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
             }

              m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);
         }
    };
    m_handlerTask.run();
```

When not required stop the run

```
        m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
```

Comment: Thanks but now the app does not display anything. Did I just place everything incorrectly. I'll re-post my code.

Comment: hello.setText(" "); do not do this add a new line hello.setText("\n ") and check the edit. increment i++ after hello.setText("\n ");

Comment: @GrahamBorland the op is using a handler and so i posted the solution.

Comment: The question is specifically about how to do it in a separate thread.

Comment: Raghunandan - I made the changes above changing setText("") to setText("\n") followed by i++; It still doesn't display.

Comment: move this to m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask); onPause()

Comment: @GrahamBorland thanks atleast you left a comment. This helped me edit my answer. I have seen users downvoting without a comment which would not help in giving a better answer

Comment: @Raghunandan - Thanks, the Thread suggestion worked (The one that got voted down.)

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters you aren't using any threads here, if you wanted to use a thread it would be something like this.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

  @Override
  public void run(){
    for(int i = 0; i < HelloWorld.length; i++){
      hello.append(HelloWorld[i]);
      Thread.sleep(1000); //wait one second
    }
  }

});
t.start();
```

However, in Android you can not update the UI from a background thread.  So you'll need to actually run the update on the UI thread, there is a helper method for that in `Activity` called `runOnUiThread`

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

  @Override
  public void run(){
    for(int i = 0; i < HelloWorld.length; i++){
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

         @Override
         public void run(){
           hello.append(HelloWorld[i]);
         }
      });
      Thread.sleep(1000); //wait one second
    }
  }

});
t.start();
```

Comment: Here's a question(Hopefully, not a stupid one) When I try implement this, eclipse yells at over sleep - telling me it's undefined and that I need a new method. How do I resolve this?

Comment: @schwiz Thread.sleep(1000) should be within try followed by catch

Answer (score 1):

While using plain Java `Threads` is good, when you have to modify the UI it's easier and better to just use [`AsyncTasks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

You can write your `AsyncTask` like this:

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    private final TextView textView;

    public Task(TextView textView) {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... update) {
        textView.append(update[0]);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (String param : params) {
            publishProgress(param);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And you are use it in your `Activity` like this:

```
Task task = new Task(hello);
task.execute("Hello", "world", "this", "is", "a", "thread");
```

Comment: This looks good, before I try to implement I have a question: How would implement this if my message was contained in a array list? how would this affect affect task.execute?

Comment: AsyncTask.execute takes only arrays. I think it's going to work with task.execute((String[]) arrayList.toArray()), or you could pass the arrayList as a parameter in the constructor.